Sources tab + F8 in Chrome inspector is not freezing the browser
I am trying to see a tooltip element in the inspector and I need to freeze the browser to do so. In the past, I've simply opened the Sources tab in the Chrome inspector, hovered over the element to get the tooltip to appear, and then hit F8. I've made quadruply sure that I am clicking only in the console before hitting F8.
For some reason, it just plain doesn't work now. When I hit F8, the tooltip disappears like I clicked somewhere else on the page and debug mode is not activated. I've never experienced this kind of behavior in Chrome DevTools and it's blocking me from completing my tests.
Here is the URL if anyone is interested in testing it out: news.ycombinator.com/newest
I am trying to view the source code of the tooltip message that shows the full timestamp for the post when the user hovers over the timestamp element under the post.

Add a DOM breakpoint on the element or parent that changes when hovering.

I actually realized it was due to a silly mistake on my part. The data I want is actually stored in a title attribute. I didn't know that title attributes work similarly to tooltips in a hover state. Thanks for your reply!

The data was stored in a title attribute, not a tooltip.
